# can you scroll a select input menu with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can use `scrollTop()` to scroll `<divs>`. however scrolling a `<select>` dropdown menu seem to be imposible? I have tried `scrollTop`, `scrollToVeiw` but nothing happens, I'm guessing its probably not possible. Please check out this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/do8tn3c5/39/) to see what I mean. Thanks

```
$('#monthYear').click(function(){
   $(this).scrollTop(0);  //does not work
});
```

Comment: Your suspicion is correct, it's not possible. If you want to do this you'd need a custom select replacement library, such as Select2

Comment: One way would be to `$(this).prop('selectedIndex',0);` on click. But that will select the first option first, and you'd have to click again to open the select menu ...